# Exclude Win10_Emulator from Visual Studio 2017 download

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am having a difficult time downloading Visual Studio 2017 (Community).

I want to exclude Win10_Emulator and Win10SDK

Which parameters do I pass to the offline installer exe to exclude them?
[image]